# How to Create Partition table at runtime over Apache Beam using Python

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to Create a new partition Bigquery table on runtime with following code, but i am not getting option to pass column names "_time" over which partition need to be done on my new BQ table.
Can any please please help me on it.

My Code

```
#------------Import Lib-----------------------#
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, StandardOptions
import os, sys
import argparse
import logging
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions
from datetime import datetime

#------------Set up BQ parameters-----------------------#
# Replace with Project Id
project = 'xxxx'

#plitting Of Records----------------------#

class Transaction_DB_UC2(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        logging.info(element)

        result = json.loads(element)

        data_time = result.get('_time', 'null')
        data_dest = result.get('dest', 'null')
        data_DBID = result.get('DBID', 'null')
        data_SESSIONID = result.get('SESSIONID', 'null')
        data_USERHOST = result.get('USERHOST', 'null')
        data_raw = result.get('_raw', 'null')
        data_ACTION = result.get('ACTION', 'null')
        data_host = result.get('host', 'null')
        data_result = result.get('result', 'null')
        data_DBUSER = result.get('DBUSER', 'null')
        data_OS_USERNAME = result.get('OS_USERNAME', 'null')
        data_ACTION_NAME = result.get('ACTION', 'null').replace('100','LOGON').replace('101','LOGOFF')

        return [{"_time": data_time[:-8], "dest": data_dest,  "DBID": data_DBID,  "SESSIONID": data_SESSIONID,  "_raw": data_raw,  "USERHOST": data_USERHOST,  "ACTION": data_ACTION, "host": data_host, "result": data_result, "DBUSER": data_DBUSER, "OS_USERNAME": data_OS_USERNAME, "ACTION_NAME": data_ACTION_NAME}]

def run(argv=None, save_main_session=True):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
          '--input',
          dest='input',
          help='Input file to process.')
    parser.add_argument(
        '--pro_id',
        dest='pro_id',
        type=str,
        default='ORACLE_SEC_DEFAULT',
        help='project id')
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)

    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = save_main_session
    p1 = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

    #data_f = sys.argv[1]
    logging.info('***********')
    logging.info(known_args.input)
    data_loading = (
        p1
        |'Read from File' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(known_args.input,skip_header_lines=0)
    )


    project_id = "xxxxx"
    dataset_id = 'test123'
    table_schema_DB_UC2 = ('_time:DATETIME, dest:STRING, DBID:STRING, SESSIONID:STRING, _raw:STRING, USERHOST:STRING, ACTION:STRING, host:STRING, result:STRING, DBUSER:STRING, OS_USERNAME:STRING, ACTION_NAME:STRING')

        # Persist to BigQuery
        # WriteToBigQuery accepts the data as list of JSON objects

#---------------------Index = DB-UC2----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    result = (
    data_loading
        | 'Clean-DB-UC2' >> beam.ParDo(Transaction_DB_UC2())
        | 'Write-DB-UC2' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                                                    table=known_args.pro_id,
                                                    dataset=dataset_id,
                                                    project=project_id,
                                                    schema=table_schema_DB_UC2,
                                                    create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                                                    write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND))

    result = p1.run()
    result.wait_until_finish()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  #logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
  path_service_account = 'ml-fbf8cabcder.json'
  os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = path_service_account
  run()
```

I want to create partition on filed "_time", please suggest how it can be achieved.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can do that with [`additional_bq_parameters`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/#using-time-partitioning) (Note the limitations) with the [`timePartitioning` parameter](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#timepartitioning).

> When creating a new BigQuery table, there are a number of extra parameters
> that one may need to specify. For example, clustering, partitioning, data
> encoding, etc. It is possible to provide these additional parameters by
> passing a Python dictionary as `additional_bq_parameters` ([Reference](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.15.0/_modules/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.html)).

In your case, you could add to your `WriteToBigQuery` transform the `timePartitioning` parameter with the required `type` and optional `field` fields (Note that `field` must be a top-level TIMESTAMP or DATE field):

```
additional_bq_parameters={'timePartitioning': {
        'type': 'DAY',
        'field': '_time'
    }}
```

I didn't have the time to try it out yet.  I'll try to reproduce tomorrow.
Let me know if it works for you.

#### EDIT

Finally got the chance to try the `timePartitioning` parameter to create a partitioned table and it worked.
Here is a simple pipeline code to test it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import apache_beam as beam

PROJECT='YOUR_PROJECT'
BUCKET='YOUR_BUCKET'

def run():
    argv = [
          '--project={0}'.format(PROJECT),
          '--job_name=YOUR_JOB_NAME',
          '--save_main_session',
          '--staging_location=gs://{0}/staging/'.format(BUCKET),
          '--temp_location=gs://{0}/staging/'.format(BUCKET),
          '--region=us-central1',
          '--runner=DataflowRunner'
    ]

    p = beam.Pipeline(argv=argv)

    table_schema = {'fields': [
        {'name': 'country', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
        {'name': '_time', 'type': 'DATETIME', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
        {'name': 'query', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'}]}

    additional_bq_parameters = {
            'timePartitioning': {'type': 'DAY', 'field': '_time'}}

    elements = (p | beam.Create([
            {'country': 'mexico', '_time': '2020-06-10 22:19:26', 'query': 'acapulco'},
            {'country': 'canada', '_time': '2020-12-11 15:42:32', 'query': 'influenza'},
        ]))

    elements | beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
        table='YOUR_DATASET.YOUR_NEW_TABLE',
        schema=table_schema,
        additional_bq_parameters=additional_bq_parameters,
        create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
        write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE
        )
    p.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't worked. I tried couple of options apart from you mentioned but it didn't worked, other option tried is : -  additional_bq_parameters={'timePartitioning': {
        'type': 'DAY',
        "fields": ['_time']
    }}

Comment: Did you get any error? Maybe it was caused by the inconsistency of the quotes (I edited my example)

Comment: I Tried all permutation and combinations with filed name in square brackets also but not working... code is running fine not giving any error  that bit strange.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your efforts. But looks like still issue same. New table is getting created with 2 records but it is not partitioned on date filed (_time). I just replaced Project name, bucket name and dataset name in your code. Do i need to change some some Configuration setting or some thing else over Bigquery or dataflow please suggest.

Comment: Table created  has description (Table info 
Table ID : xxxxxxxx:test123.YOUR_NEW_TABLE,
Table size :53 B,
Number of rows : 2,
Created :Dec 18, 2020, 1:58:06 AM,
Table expiration :Never,
Last modified : Dec 18, 2020, 1:58:06 AM,
Data location : EU)

Comment: I am expecting addition table description as(  Table type :Partitioned, 
Partitioned by :Day,
Partitioned on field : _time,
Partition filter : Not required)

Comment: I have been able to reproduce the code provided in this answer, just changing the dataset name, table name, bucket name and project name. Could you please run this code and then run the following SQL query in BigQuery? SELECT column_name, is_partitioning_column FROM `YOURPROJECT.YOURDATASET.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` WHERE table_name = "YOURTABLE" AND is_partitioning_column = "YES" .This query should return the name of any column by which your table is partitioned

Comment: Please make sure you put the backticks (``) around YOURPROJECT.YOURDATASET.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS as stackoverflow is detecting this as markdown and I have not managed to change this behaviour